# How to compare continuous data for a categorical response variable?

Tags: categorical-data, anova

Apologies for an extremely basic question but I have an analysis block (analogous to writer's block). I have the following data:

```
Location<-c(Site1, Site2, Site 3)
Rainfall <-c(34.5,54.6,182.1,261.1,192.1,201.2,121.1,198.5,167.7)
Temp<-c(17.2,15.1,22.2,18.9,10,1,21.1,15.0,13.3,16.7)
Wind <-(20.7,10.3,25.1,04.5,18.2,10.4,03.7,08.1,19.1)
```

Now I want to see how these variables differ site-wise. Question: If there is any significant difference between the sites in relation to rainfall, temperature or wind. What is the appropriate analysis to do so? I tried ANOVA but the response variable has to be continuous for that and as I understand my response variable will have to be Sites. Any help is appreciated, I cannot figure this one out.